# Transfer the input on string array then to a char array

Tags: java, arrays, char

Im trying to practice for loops and transferring input to arrays. I have a problem on transferring an input to a string array then to a char array (a single letter). I have tried `in.next().charAt(t)` but I dont know why I am having an error. First I used `charArr[t] = in.nextLine()`. It said that I needed to convert it. Then I created a string array and used `charArr[t] = string[t];`  also said I need to convert it first. Is there anyway to transfer my input from the string array to the character array? Thank you

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
{
    

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int range = 0;

 
    System.out.print("Please enter the range: ");
    range = Integer.parseInt(in.nextLine());

    String[] string = new String[range];
    char[] charArr = new char[range];
    System.out.println("Please enter the characters: ");
    for(int t = 0; t < range; t++){
        string[t] = in.nextLine(); //First input to the string array
        charArr[t] = string[t]; //Attempt to transfer that letter/input
        
    }
    
}
```

Comment: typically a `String` is an array of characters. Your `string` variable is an array of `String` objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following code:

```
//The character array to store the string characters
char[] charArr = new char[range];

//Get the string
System.out.println("Please enter the characters: ");
String string = in.nextLine();

//Copy the string to the character array one letter at a time
for(int t = 0; t < string.length(); t++){
    charArr[t] = string.charAt(t); 
}
```

Note how we use a single string to store the input `String string = in.nextLine();`, we don't need a string array. Once we have the string we can transfer the characters one at a time into the character array.

If you want to process multiple strings to store in a string array `String[] string = new String[range];` then we can use a nested loop:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
int range = 0;


System.out.print("How many strings do you want to process?");
range = Integer.parseInt(in.nextLine());

String[] string = new String[range];
for(int t = 0; t < range; t++){
    //We need a new char array for each input string
    char[] charArr = new char[range];

    //Get the text string
    System.out.println("Please enter the characters: ");
    string[t] = in.nextLine();

    //Copy the string to the character array one letter at a time
    for(int i = 0; i < string[t].length(); i++){
        charArr[i] = string[t].charAt(i); 
    }
    //Print the character array here or add it to an array of arrays...
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding what you want to do correctly (convert each inputted string into an array of characters and store them in `charArr`), you need to make `charArr` two dimensional and then transfer each character of each inputted string into it. Try something like the following:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int range = 0;

    System.out.print("Please enter the range: ");
    range = Integer.parseInt(in.nextLine());

    String[] string = new String[range];
    // notice that this is now a two dimensional array. the first dimension
    // is range, and the second is the number of chars in each string
    char[][] charArr = new char[range][];
    System.out.println("Please enter the characters: ");
    for (int t = 0; t < range; t++) {
        string[t] = in.nextLine();
        // String has a function toCharArray that can handle this
        charArr[t] = string[t].toCharArray();
        // alternately, you can write another loop
        charArr[t] = new char[string[t].length()];
        for (int charIndex = 0; charIndex < string[t].length(); charIndex++) {
            charArr[t][charIndex] = string[t].charAt(charIndex);
        }
    }
}
```

Note that I outlined two separate ways of doing the same thing above. Please remove the one you don't want to use. Between them, `String.toCharArray` is the more concise and idiomatic option.